# "Computed property must have an explicit type" error: how to list files in Swift 2.x?

Tags: ios, swift, try-catch

The following code generates a `Computed property must have an explicit type error.`

What's the right way to list files with the new `try/catch` Swift syntax?

```
do {
       let files = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(docsPath as String) as! [String] {
       print("Found \(files.count) file(s) in \(docsPath):")
}catch{
       print("Error with listing files: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Is it really a duplicate when the question covers finding a specific error in the OPs code?

Comment: @dfri agreed it isn't a duplicate because of the specific error and your specific solution.

Comment: @dfri in this case it should be closed as a typo

Comment: @LeoDabus _This_ I do agree to, after just reading [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions) for the first time. Since it's been solved for the OP, I see no reason of keeping it. Too localized to be of use for anyone else, I believe.

Comment: I got this error also when I forgot to put the `if` keyword in the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've added an extra curly bracket `{` after your try statement (after `... as! [String]`) that is not needed. This extra curly bracket makes Swift believe that you're working with a computed property.

Remove the bracket and your `do-try-catch` block should work :

```
var docsPath : String = "notavalidpath"
do {
    let files = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(docsPath as String) as! [String]
    print("Found \(files.count) file(s) in \(docsPath):")
}catch{
    print("Error with listing files: \(error)")
}
```